# Custome vue bootstrap theme is not working

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use vue bootstrap and I want to set custom colors for my theme I also want to allow my users to switch to a dark theme with a button. I installed vue-bootstrap I have it working just fine I went and followed the instructions on bootstrap4 how to customize the theme so I made a custom.scss file in my assets folder and added this code.

```
$theme-colors: (
    "kimbel-prime": #091F40,
    "kimbel-success": #7FC343,
    "kimbel-warn": #C74241,
    "kimbel-danger": #6E0C2B
);

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

in order to use this I read on a github site that you ahve to import all of this inside your app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
      <b-button variant="kimbel-primary"> I am a Button </b-button>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  @import "assets/custom.scss";
  @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
  @import '~bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
#nav {
  padding: 30px;
  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2c3e50;
    &.router-link-exact-active {
      color: #42b983;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

I added this and was hoping to see my button get the new color but it still had just a button color any help would be greatly apperciated this is my first time I am trying to use vue so forgive me for anything I am missing. I think I can tackle switching to a dark theme after I get this working.

Comment: i think the order of importing your `.scss` files matters

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim so in app.vue you think I need to re-order the imports?

Comment: in the `style` section